# anchor tag to move to section not working after scroll in html

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll, menu

i have a website specifically for mobile, its a scroll down website where when a user scrolls down they get to see sections. i have given a menu to it and when user clicks on the menu it should take to different sections.

```js
function myFunctione() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#1s" onclick="myFunctione(); " style="cursor:pointer">Home</a>
    <a href="#2s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Menu</a>
    <a href="#3s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Stores</a>
    <a href="#4s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Franchise</a>
    <a href="#5s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Shark Tank</a>
    <a href="#6s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Oh So Special</a>
    <a href="#7s" onclick="myFunctione()" style="cursor:pointer">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="1s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="2s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="3s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="4s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="5s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="6s">
  ...............
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="7s">
  ...............
  </div>
```

when the user uses the menu button without scrolling, the button is working fine, but when the user scrolls to some section and then use menu button, its not working, sometimes the sections are also coming misaligned while too much scrolling.
this is my live url:
[live](https://demo.thebrandchimp.com/cocofit/mobile/)
can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have this scrollling JS running.  When you swipe up or down it adds a `style="top: -2180.95px;"` (or whatever position) to the `#superContainer` element which isn't really a scroll, it's a forced positioning.

Once that happens navigating to a hash ID will no longer work because you've forced the element to be offset by whatever amount.

You can test this by opening the devtools, swiping down and you see the forced positioning being added, and yes the menu links no longer work.  Now go into the devtools and remove that positioning that was added and the menu will work when clicked.

My suggestion is to remove this wierd swipe up/down auto-scroll JS.  Just let people scroll like normal.  It's easer to navigate, less disorienting, and all your buttons will work.

Comment: is there any other alternate solution? coz the website is designed in that format, user should scroll from section to section only

Comment: Yes, you can make those menu clicks scroll the page jus like swiping does.  Click a menu item and run the same JS that scrolls the page, but to a specific position instead of the "next" one like swiping up/down would.  I don't know how this animated scrolling works, I saw some jQuery imports in your code, so probably some plugin.

Comment: actually my website is something like this https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page2 , here they have same scrolling effect and their buttons are also working